# Persisting logged in user information

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I know this is a simple concept, but I need some help. I'm creating a winforms app, in c#, and I'm trying to organize my code. The first screen is a log in, and once the user is authenticated I return the users details. How/where should I store these details so that I don't have to retrieve them again each time I want to use them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the lines of what the others have said about the global static class, but with some sample code :

```
public class UserInfo
{
    private int userID;

    public int UserID
    {
        get { return userID; }
    }

    private string userName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
    }

    public UserInfo(int userID, string userName)
    {
        this.userID = userID;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}

public static class GlobalInfo
{
    private static UserInfo currentUser;

    public static UserInfo CurrentUser
    {
        get { return currentUser; }
        set { currentUser = value; }
    }
}
```

So, after the user has logged in, save the logged in info :

```
GlobalInfo.CurrentUser = new UserInfo(123, "Bob Jones");
```

When you need to fetch info :

```
UserInfo userInfo = GlobalInfo.CurrentUser;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a global static class as answered in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293926/c-winforms-global-variables) or look at a [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) implementation

... or read this [question "Global variable approach in C# Windows Forms application? (is public static class GlobalData the best)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515173/global-variable-approach-in-c-windows-forms-application-is-public-static-class) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a singleton as @brodie says, but implemented as an instance of the user details object pushed into a DI container. For example, [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) supports [binding to a instance](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Planning/Bindings/BindingBuilder.cs) via `BindToConstant`. So you would have your `LoggedInUser` instance (details of the logged in user) created when the user logs in, then `Bind<LoggedInUser>.ToConstant(myLoggedInUser)` (from memory). Then if you need to get the logged in user you would just pull the current instance from the DI container (via something like `kernel.Get<LoggedInUser>()`).